# Synchronizing databases using WSO2

Tags: database, synchronization, wso2

I need to sync two databases (one way, origin *read-only* Oracle, destination Postgres, BLOB fields included, **about 50 TB**) and then keep it synced.

I have no experience with WSO2, please, tell me if this synchronization could be done with it and which product I should use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are other products from AWS being available - DMS, SNOWBALL to sync the databases. Those are however useful if your DBs are in hosted in AWS CLOUD.
If you can explore writing custom solution, I can share with you the approach. I had done similar work in syncing data across heterogeneous systems from MS SQL to MONGODB continuously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My DBs are on-premises. I found https://www.symmetricds.org/ and I will give it a chance. Thanks for your time @SunilSinghal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 does not have OOTB product intended for DB synching. However you can utilize [WSO2 DAS](https://wso2.com/analytics#download) to do this task. In brief What you need to do is connect both DBs as [datasources](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Configuring+an+RDBMS+Datasource) into WSO2 DAS. Oracle datasource config example is [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Setting+up+Oracle). postgre config example is [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Setting+up+PostgreSQL). Use your own datasource name and jndi name instead of carbon DB. 
Then write a [spark](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Spark+Query+Language) [incremental](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Incremental+Processing) script connecting to two datasources using [CarbonJDBC connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Creating+the+Table+Using+Carbon+JDBC+as+the+Provider) to copy all records. Finally you can [schedule](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Scheduling+Batch+Analytics+Scripts) the script using a cron expression.

This may not be the perfect solution. But this should work. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks @Tishan! I will try it.